# Edit particular field in a row of the table and update edited value in MySQL table

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysqli

I am fetching data from database in a table.Now i want to edit particular field in a row of the table and save that value into MySQL.

This is my complete code for displaying data in table and editing. Here i want to edit the status. It is editable but after editing how to get the value from the table and update that value to MySQL.

```
 <?php
include "config.php";
$sql = "select * from d_jobs where Status ='drafted' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
//echo $count;
?>



<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

$("document").ready(function(){

$('#sdata').click(function(){

    var myTxt = $(('.status')+[i]).html();
    console.log(myTxt);
    var id = $(('.status')+[i]).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
    }
    /* $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url:  'job_field_edit.php',
        data: 'varname=' +myTxt 
    }); */

});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<table border="2" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Job Name</th>
      <th>Builder</th>
      <th>Job Type</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Effective Date Start</th>
       <th>Estimated completion date</th>
        <th>Job Gal Glag</th>
         <th>Take List Flag</th>
          <th>Planner</th>
           <th>Project Manager</th>
           <th>Hand Over</th>
           <th>Other Comments</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
      if( $count ==0 ){
        echo '<tr><td colspan="4">No Rows Returned</td></tr>';
      }else{
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr><td>{$row['JOB_NAME']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['BUILDER']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['JOB_TYPE']}</td>
                  <td contenteditable='true' id='{$row['JOB_ID']}' class='status[{$row['JOB_ID']}]'>{$row['status']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['EFFECTIVE_START_DATE']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_DATE']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['JOB_GAL_FLAG']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['JOB_TAKE_LIST_FLAG']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['Planner']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['Project_Manager']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['Handover']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['Comments']}</td>
                  <td><input name='need_delete[{$row['JOB_ID']}]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[{$row['JOB_ID']}]' value='{$row['JOB_ID']}'></td>
                  </tr>\n";
        }
      }
 ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input id="sdata" type="button" value="Send Data" />
</body>
</html>
<?php

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of ways to approach this. One is to dispense with the manual `Send Data` button and allow javascript to respond automatically to users' `contenteditable` edits.

Unfortunately, `contenteditable` elements don't fire a `change` event but they do fire a `blur` event, from which a `change` event can be triggered.

First, build your `contenteditable` elements like this :

```
<td contenteditable=\"true\" class=\"status\" data-job-id=\"{$row['JOB_ID']}\">{$row['status']}</td>
```

Then, for each `contenteditable` element, attach a `blur` handler, and initialize a `data-value` attribute equal to `innerText`.

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('blur', function(e) {
    var self = $(this);
    if(self.text() !== self.data('value')) {
        self.trigger('change');
    }
    self.data('value', self.text());
}).each(function() {
    $(this).data('value', $(this).text()); // equivaluent to data-value="{$row['status']}".
});
```

Thus you can have `contenteditable` elements that mimic, at least in part, HTML input elements.

So now you can attach a `change` handler as you would for a standard HTML input element.

```
$(".status").on('change', function(e) {
    var job_id = $(this).data('jobId');
    var old value = $(this).data('value');
    var current value = $(this).text(); // in this regard, <input> is not mimicked. For a genuine <input> we would write `$(this).val()`.

    // here, perform ajax to keep server-side up to date.
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fd9u17jn/)**

Note: This approach is slightly over-the-top when `[contenteditable]` and `.status` are virtual synonyms for each other. However, in the general case where there might be several different classes of `contenteditable` element, then you would likely avoid much repetition of code.